# What would be the error of the email method?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

The previous settings of port, authentication, and protocol are correct for you sending the email.

And as a result i get a message like the one in the image.

**Without a message and without attachment, I just get the signature by default in the mail.**

thanks;

```
 @Autowired
    public Session emailSession;

    @Override
    public JsonObject sendEmail(final JsonObject json) throws CommunicationsException {

        final JsonObject response = new JsonObject();

        final String receiver = (String) json.get(RECEIVER);
        final String subject = (String) json.get(SUBJECT);
        final String messageBody = (String) json.get(MESSAGE_BODY);
        final String attachment = (String) json.get(ATTACHMENT);
        try {

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(MAIL_USER_FROM));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receiver));
        msg.setSubject(subject);

        Multipart emailContenido = new MimeMultipart();

        // Text
        MimeBodyPart textoBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        textoBodyPart.setText(messageBody);

        // Att
        MimeBodyPart adjunto = new MimeBodyPart();
        adjunto.attachFile("C:/hola.txt");

        // Parts email
        emailContenido.addBodyPart(textoBodyPart);
        emailContenido.addBodyPart(adjunto);

        msg.setContent(emailContenido);

        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("Message ok");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, what do you expect to happen?  Without a message and without an attachment, what do you expect to receive?

Comment: Good morning Bill Shannon, what I want to happen is that i get a message with text, and with the attachment you. Because i get empty and without attachment. Thanks;

Comment: I think we're having an English problem here....  Using the code above, that sends a message with text and an attachment, what you actually get is a message with no text and no attachment, is that correct?  Turn on [JavaMail Session debugging](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) and post the debug output.